# Regex find arbitrary string of characters determined at runtime

Tags: c#, regex

A regex needs to be constructed at runtime (using C# in my case) to find a given string surrounded by some pattern. For example, the program knows it needs to find `myString` ending in whitespace inside `targetString`. If we set the regex to just be

```
string myRegex = myString + @"\s";
```

then the regex won't be reliable if `myString` contains regex control characters like . + etc. For example say that

```
myString = "f.f";
targetString = "f.ff fff f.f ff";
```

then the regex `myRegex` above will match the first `fff` which is not what we want. Of course, the correct regex is `f\.f\s` but converting `myString` to such a form would be messy given the large number of regex control characters.

Is there a way to generate such a regex with an arbitrary input string? Ideally there would be some control characters that can be used to wrap around `myString` to indicate that the string needs to match literally. So in my fantasy, the regex could be generated with something like

```
string myRegex = @"{{" + myString + @"}}\s";
```

where the braces represent the magical structure that I am looking for.

Please note that the pattern surrounding the `myString` may be more complex than simply "ending with `\s`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`Regex.Escape()`:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string myRegex = Regex.Escape(myString) + @"\s";
```

Comment: Thanks, I will also need to make sure `myString` is matched case sensitively though. I suppose this combined with turning off the `i` flag will do it.